# Access change query expression based on last modified date for linked table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a linked table with a a column name "2012 Full Units w/c"  At some point this year the data will be updated and that column will change to "2013 Full Units w/c".  When this happens, I want the query to pull this new data into this column instead.  The time at which this data will change is uncertain.  However this update will be on the first update of this linked file for the year.

Currently I explicitly query this table by referencing "2012 Full Units w/c".  How can I use the last modified date to grab this information in a way that will accommodate this uncertain timed change in column title?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use some VBA code to test whether the old field name still exists, something like this:

```vbs
Sub CheckForFieldNameChange()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, errNo As Long
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    cdb.TableDefs("YourLinkedTable").RefreshLink
    On Error GoTo CheckForFieldNameChange_Error
    Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
            "SELECT TOP 1 [2012 Full Units w/c] " & _
            "FROM [YourLinkedTable]", _
            dbOpenSnapshot)
    Debug.Print "Field name has not changed yet."
    rst.Close
CheckForFieldNameChange_Exit:
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
    Exit Sub

CheckForFieldNameChange_Error:
    errNo = Err.Number
    Select Case errNo
        Case 3061
            Debug.Print "Field name has changed."
            GoTo CheckForFieldNameChange_Exit
        Case Else
            Err.Raise errNo
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If by `Last Modified Date` you mean a field within the table then you can use something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT Year(Max([Last Modified])) FROM TableName) & " Full Units w/c" AS FieldName
FROM TableName
```

But if you are referring to the actual date the table in question was last modified you may need some VBA to facilitate like the following:

```
Public Function tblLastModified(tblName As String) As Date

    tblLastModified = CurrentDb.TableDefs(tblName).LastUpdated

End Function
```

Then your query would be:

```
SELECT (SELECT Year(tblLastModified("TableName")) FROM TableName) & " Full Units w/c" AS FieldName
FROM TableName
```